# Swift fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm creating a game as a small project and i'm trying to make it so after ever 5 points the walls will generate more but when playing the game, it crashes at reaching around 24 points with the the error "fatal error: Array index out of range"

GameScene.swift

```
 if pointsLabel.number % kNumberOfPointsPerLevel == 0 {
                    currentLevel++
                    wallGenerator.stopGenerating()
                    wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(kLevelGenerationTimes[currentLevel])
                }
```

Constants.swift

```
let kNumberOfPointsPerLevel = 5
let kLevelGenerationTimes: [NSTimeInterval] = [1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3]
```

Comment: So what is the currentLevel when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is here:

```
wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(kLevelGenerationTimes[currentLevel])
```

when `currentLevel` is equal to or greater than the number of elements in `kLevelGenerationTimes`.

I don't know what the correct solution is, depending on your game logic - I would propose 2 versions, the first restarting from the first element of that array once the end is reached:

```
wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(kLevelGenerationTimes[currentLevel % kLevelGenerationTimes.count])
```

whereas the second is to always use the last element of the array (I take that as an increasing complexity as the player progresses):

```
let index = currentLevel < kLevelGenerationTimes.count ? currentLevel : kLevelGenerationTimes.count - 1
wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(kLevelGenerationTimes[index])
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `kLevelGenerationTimes[currentLevel]` where `currentLevel` gets incremented every time `pointsLabel.number % kNumberOfPointsPerLevel == 0`.

`kLevelGenerationTimes` only has 5 elements (`[1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3]`) and with the rate at which you increase the level

```
Points: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
Level : 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  5
```

At `25` points, `currentLevel` becomes `5` which is an invalid index for your array.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you have an array with **5 cells** with index **from 0 to 4**.

If you try to access the array with a index outside this range the app will crash.

Example:

```
let kLevelGenerationTimes: [NSTimeInterval] = [1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3]

kLevelGenerationTimes[0] // ok
kLevelGenerationTimes[1] // ok
kLevelGenerationTimes[2] // ok
kLevelGenerationTimes[3] // ok
kLevelGenerationTimes[4] // ok
kLevelGenerationTimes[5] // crash!!!
```